# Calling a method from inside onload() when dynamically injecting JS from Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

[This fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/1101095) shows how you can dynamically insert JavaScript into a page from a Chrome extension:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
// TODO: add "script.js" to web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

When the `onload()` function is called, it's executed in the browser page's isolated world, not the extension's isolated world, right?

Assuming that's correct, I'm having an problem I don't understand.

Inside of my `script.js` I have code similar to this:

```
var globalObj = globalObj || {};
globalObj.method = function () {
    console.log('hey!');
};
```

Then I changed the `onload()` function above to:

```
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);

    globalObj.method();
};
```

But the console shows the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: globalObj is not defined
```

Why isn't `globalObj` defined inside of the `onload()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onload` executes in the content script context, and not in the page context.

To communicate between page context and script context, you can use various methods; for example, a custom DOM event will achieve what you need here:

```
// Content script
s.onload = function() {
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  var event = new CustomEvent("invokeMethod");
};

// script.js
window.addEventListener("invokeMethod", function(evt) {
  globalObj.method();
}, false);
```